# Can I recover Android for Galaxy S4 after installing other operation system?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, factory-reset

I want to try to use ubuntu on my Galaxy S4 Active. Is there possible to recover Android from Samsung for Galaxy S4 after my using Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You must make a nandroid backup of your android before making any changes to it. If you made a nandroid backup, then yes.. You can recover android later anytime you want.

Comment: Can you give me the offical link?

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2649691

Comment: Follow the guide.. . Install cwm provided for your device. Then make a complete backup using CWM. Take care that you have at least 2-3 gb free on your sdcard as the complete backup of your device would be large.